# KendoNumericTextBox decimal rounding issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net MVC application I am using Kendo grid to display data from a database table. Below code is used to display the "Price" column up to six decimal places. It displays "Price" value fine on load but when I click on Price to edit,its values automatically rounded off to two decimal place. For example, if it loads value 456.345674 from database, in edit mode textbox will round off the value to 456.35 I don't want values to be rounded off to two places. It should keep decimal places intact. Please suggest.

```
{
    field: "Price",
    type: "number",
    filterable: {
        cell: {
            template: function (args) {
                args.element.kendoNumericTextBox({
                    format: "#.######",
                    decimals:6
                });
            },
            operator: "gte"
        }
    },
    width: 140
}
```

Answer (score 1):

KendoNumericTextBox ain't expecting a `#.######` format.  If you want to force 6 decimals, the correct format would be `n6`.  If you want to display the entire number without rounding, the format would be `n`.

You can refer to [kendo's number formatting documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting) to see what are the available formats.